# Get Created date time of new columns added to existing tables

Tags: mysql

Sorry if this is a simple question but i have a problem.

I have been adding new columns to many tables in my local db . i.e MYSQL
I want to deploy the changes to production database and i have not maintained any text file to mention the changes i have made.

So how to get created or updated datetime of columns added to existing tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table which might contain this information would be the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table.  The only problem is that it doesn't appear to record a timestamp when a column was added/altered.  I can offer a workaround which might be just as fast.  You may run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on the table running in production, and then do the same on your dev version.  Then, just use any reputable diff checking tool (e.g. [DiffChecker.com](http://www.diffchecker.com)) and look for the differences.

Moving forward, you should keep better track of the changes you make to your table during development.  A much better approach, I think, would be to just keep track of the alter statements which you run on the table.  Then, deploy these changes when you send everything to production.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.Situation is-
1)I don't have access to prod db 2) Unluckily information_schema.colums dont have timestamp column 3) Alter statement is best solution,foolishly i don't have them.So memorizing is only the way